# How can I split a string by a delimiter in Java?

Tags: java, string

I want to make a simple program that can convert currencies and weights, etc. The only problem is that I don't know how to separate a string so that I can get each individual word.

So, if I have the string `"200 GBP USD"`, how can I separate it so that I get

```
int currency = 200;
String currencyFrom = "GBP";
String currencyTo = "USD";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? It is best if you make an effort to solve it yourself before posting a question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: scanner provides lot of methods like `nextInt()`, `next()`. Why don't you use those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `split`:

```
String[] words = yourString.split(" ");
int currency = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
String currencyFrom = words[1];
String currencyTo = words[2];
```

Answer (score 4):

Just split the string using the String.split function.

```
String[] Parts = input.split(" ");
if(Parts.length>2)
{
    int currency = Integer.parseInt(Parts[0]);
    String currencyFrom = Parts[1];
    String currencyTo = Parts[2];
}
```